# Entity Framework Code First Shared Data Layer, bad model?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6, shared-libraries, dbcontext

I have a solution.  In it there are 2 libraries:
1. EntityLibrary - This houses just the basic entity objects
2. ContextLibrary - This houses the dbContext and the migration records

Also there are 2 WinForm Apps
1. App1
2. App2

Both Apps use both libraries.  Both Apps have the same connection string in their config files.  Both apps are on 4.5.2 of .Net.  Both apps are using EF 6.0.0.  Both Apps have the same "entityFramework" section and "connectionStrings" section in their app.configs.

App1 works fine.  App2 reports that "The model backing the context has changed since the database was created..."

Why does App2 not work?  Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested.  This actually was about how to check your version of Entity Framework it turns out.  I was using the version in the app.config and the version on the library (in references).  Turns out these stay the same for all the 6.x.x versions.  You have to check the packages.config file to find the right answer.

So it turned out I was using 2 different versions of EF.  Once I fixed that, everything worked as expected.